# Broadcasting CCTV Camera

Tags: javascript, camera

I just wanted to embed my wifi camera video to a website. I have seen that it's possible to do so using RTSP. The problem is that my camera doesn't support RTSP. Is there any way to do so without RTSP? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to involve your backend in that you can stream using either [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/) or a normal javascript [getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia)

Answer (score -1):

Connect Your RTSP camera to your router LAN or WiFi network

Login to your Management Panel

Click on All Media button in the left hand navigation bar.

Now click on the Add Media button located on the top Media view.

Select the Live IP Cams tab.

Here you can enter a Player Title to identify your Live IP Cam Player in the future.

Comment: _"Connect Your RTSP camera to your router"_ but _"The problem is that my camera doesn't support RTSP"_